# How can python's os.system([command]) bypass the history record?

Tags: linux, python, history

I mean, how *dare* it?
These two scripts have different record in history (at least by history command)

```
# echo "hello"
```

the direct command in shell will result in a record in history, however if I execute it inside python

```
# python
# import os
# os.system("echo 'hello'")
```

However, the second way of executing a shell script bypass the history record. And can I find the echo command from python somewhere on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `history` accesses the `.bash_history` file. Only commands directly executed by a user in a shell get logged to the bash_history.

Commands executed by scripts or other software are not logged by default.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. But doesn't this pose a security threat that some hackers could leave the operations unrecorded?

Comment: AFAIK the `bash_history` file is not meant to be a security feature. It's more of a convenience feature. It lets you see or repeat (arrow up) commands that you've previously used. There are some tools that log executed commands. But even they don't guarantee to log everything.

Apart from scripts executing commands one could just execute a command in a shell and then edit the `.bash_history` file to remove the logged command.

Comment: I also believe adding a space before your command, ie ` echo hi`, will prevent adding the bash command to history. Not sure about all systems, but on rhel / ubuntu it seems to do so.